# import kotlinx is impossible in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin

I`m testing coroutine example code on IntelliJ IDEA. But I cannot import library which needs for coroutine.

I created project as Kotlin - "JVM | IDEA". I tried simple print hello world code and succeesfully done. But coroutine example don`t even execute.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Mutex
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.withLock


fun main()
{
    runBlocking {

      var counter = 0
      val lock = Mutex()  

      val coroutines = List(3) {
        launch {
          repeat(1_000) {
            lock.withLock {
              counter++
            }
          }
        }
      }

      coroutines.forEach { it.join() }

      println("Final counter: $counter")
    }
}
```

This Code runs on https://play.kotlinlang.org. But in IDEA, they cannot understand it, showing 'Unresolved reference'.

I`ve searched but no answer found. How can I run this on IDEA project?

Comment: You need to declare all dependencies. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines

Comment: The code works fine on Intellij IDEA 2019.1, kotlin 1.3.31 without any changes.

Comment: @Nolequen How did you setup these dependencies? I made 'Gradle Kotlin Build Script' and pasted them to file but nothing did work well.

Comment: you may refer to official documentation about how to setup kotlin project using gradle: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: @Nolequen I need your help. I am newbie at this and I cannot find any right place to set a code. When I tried running kts, it shows some bulb icon. After clicked it, IDEA added some jar for running kotlin script at KotlinJavaRuntime.xml

    <root url="jar://$KOTLIN_BUNDLED$/lib/kotlin-script-runtime.jar!/" />

Then I thought if i add something correct, it will run. But of course failed. Should I use other project like Gradle - Kotlin/JVM or Java - Kotlin/JVM to setting well? I will try more. Please give me some hint that I can use

Comment: I gave up using kotlin - JVM | IDEA. I make another one using Gradle - Kotlin/JVM and there is default build.gradle for setting. Finally successed

Comment: @Temp I'm glad that everything worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

it would be a good idea to switch to a Gradle-based build, which will automatically be imported by IntelliJ IDEA.

you can set IntelliJ to [automatically stay in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192504/how-do-i-disable-or-enable-gradle-maven-auto-import-for-an-intellij-idea-proje) with your Gradle files, or you can opt to "sync" IntelliJ to Gradle's structure on demand.

you have two syntax options with Gradle: Groovy and Kotlin. make sure if you are new to Gradle that you use a consistent syntax, otherwise it can be hard to follow the guides. obviously if you are working in Kotlin, it's a great idea to use Kotlin in your build files, too.