# Intelliji-idea cannot find jar on web

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I try to add some import for groovy file.

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials
```

Try to use option "Find jar on web". As a result I see message "No libraries found for groovyx.net.http.RESTClient".
Same problem was for java projects with adding junit and jsoup libraries, but I just downloaded them.

Where can be a problem?

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/
```

are used as remote jar repositories

build.gradle file content:

```
apply plugin: "groovy"

group = "ru.ftc.cs.test"
version = "1.0.0"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://diesel.ftc.ru:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/" }
}

dependencies {

    testCompile group: "org.codehaus.groovy"                      , name: "groovy-all"  , version: "2.4.5"
    testCompile group: "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder" , name: "http-builder", version: "0.7.1"
    testCompile group: "org.spockframework"                       , name: "spock-core"  , version: "1.0-groovy-2.4"
}
```

**Decision:**
I need only to run build.gradle correct way to solve a problem.

Comment: Please share your build script maven or gradle.

Comment: @user2738882 added build.gradle file content to question

Comment: Have you enabled `automatic import` in Gradle?

Comment: @Mike Thanks for help, I worked with gradle for 1st time.

Comment: `auto import` can be enabled in Intellij-idea. Follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192504/how-do-i-redisable-gradle-auto-import-for-an-intellij-idea-project. Only do the opposite :).