# Intellij IDEA stopped prompting me to import changes

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have gradle Java projects in IDEA. It used to prompt me for importing the changes I made in build.gradle. Recently it stops doing that. Now, I have to manually to do "Invalidate caches and restart" from the File menu to bring in the new packages every time I make changes to build.gradle. I look at online but could not find any helpful information.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192764/104891 help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for the quick response. My problem is that the IDE doesn't prompt me for my change in build.gradle. It used to work until a while ago. The link talks about the auto import which I'd like to keep the default setting (disable).

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Did you note that this option was removed and replaced with the icon in the editor? Do you see this icon? https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/01/intellij-idea-2020-1-eap/#maven_and_gradle_importing_updates .

Comment: @CrazyCoder I was using 19.3 when the problem started to occur. Recently, I upgraded it to 20.1. The problem stays.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) and a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks, @CrazyCoder. Reported to JetBrains. Ticket # is IDEA-238733.