# maven offers itself postgreSQL driver dependency but then doesn't see it

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jdbc, dependencies

I tried to connect PostgreSQL connector driver with maven but it doesn't find this dependency

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to add driver as .jar file with Project structure and it worked, but I want to add it just like dependency in maven.

Answer (score 2):

Since IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1, it will no longer automatically import updates from your pom.xml when you make changes within the IDE (it will import when - for example - updating from version control). You need to explicitly import changes by clicking the floating refresh button (see top right corner inside your pom.xml view) for the changes to your pom.xml to be processed.

As far as I know, the reason for this change is to prevent multiple time-consuming imports when you are updating your pom files.

As indicated in the comments by CrazyCoder, IntelliJ 2020.1.2 will introduce an option to enable automatic import for any changes again.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192764/104891. IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2 RC already has a new 3-state option for automatic importing: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2020.1+latest+builds.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That option exists for Gradle, but as far as I can tell not for Maven.

Comment: No, it [exists for Maven as well](https://i.imgur.com/eJhzVjP.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder It is interesting that the button already exists in 2020.1.1 for Gradle, but not for Maven. I assume they added this in 2020.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood it was IDEA problem. I used "mvn clean compile" in terminal and idea started see the dependency