# Maven Springboot Web dependency not found?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add Spring Boot to a maven project and i'm getting the following error and it's not being recgonized and allowing me to add dependencies 
"Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.1.RELEASE' not found"
[Here is an image of my dependencies block in the pom.xml file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUYbH.png)
I am unsure what i am doing incorrectly.

Comment: add spring boor parent and check. Refer https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ 2020?

Comment: the instructor in my lecture recording just added it into his pom.xml w/o installing anything prior? @KathirvelSubramanian

Comment: @stdunbar yes i am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ 2020 has one of the worst user interfaces in the history of computing when it comes to Maven.  Look for the tiny:

[image]

towards the upper right hand part of the IntelliJ window when you're in your `pom.xml`.  Click on the "M" refresh logo and that will reload your pom.xml and resolve dependencies.

Comment: Starting with 2020.1.2 version there is a new 3-state option so that the changes can be imported automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192504/how-do-i-redisable-gradle-auto-import-for-an-intellij-idea-project.

Comment: I see I'm not allowed to express an opinion @CrazyCoder

Comment: Your opinion is appreciated, but would be better expressed in the relevant ticket, than in the answer to the specific user question: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-235459. As you can tell from the votes count, you are not alone and it was indeed a poor solution to the problem.

Comment: I did open a ticket - but not someone starting out may not have seen that.