# WebClient not resolving

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea

In order to utilise the new `WebClient` API, I've included `spring-webflux` in my Intellij project.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
//    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webflux', version: '5.2.7.RELEASE'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

However, WebClient remains unresolved:

```
C:\Users\tobia\Documents\spring-app\service\Service.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(WebClient.Builder());
                           ^
  symbol:   variable WebClient
  location: class Service
```

---

The dependency itself seems to have resolved, as `webflux` is now in my "external libraries" list:

[image]

---

Does anybody have any idea why `WebClient` remains unresolved?

---

I've tried all 4 of these dependency declerations, and none work:

```
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webflux', version: '5.2.7.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webflux', version: '5.2.7.RELEASE'
```

Comment: Try the second one it works for me [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webflux/5.2.7.RELEASE).

Comment: @chriptus13 doesn't fix error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `build.gradle` is missing this dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webflux', version: '5.2.7.RELEASE'
```

Proof of working:

[image: WebClient]

Make sure to [reimport the dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192764/104891).

The sample code for `WebClient` should look like this:

```
        WebClient client3 = WebClient
                .builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                .defaultCookie("cookieKey", "cookieValue")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultUriVariables(Collections.singletonMap("url", "http://localhost:8080"))
                .build();
```

Notice that it's `WebClient.builder()` and not `WebClient.Builder()`, it looks like you have a typo in the method name, replace `Builder()` with `builder()` and it should work.

`WebClient.Builder` is an Interface, therefore this code is not valid:

```
System.out.println(WebClient.Builder());
```

It's a **syntax issue with you code** that has nothing to do with Gradle, dependencies or IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: This doesn't work, I tried it (which is why it was commented out)

Comment: Please see the updated answer showing that it works fine.

Comment: I had to invalidate my caches, for some reason.

Comment: It's a syntax issue with you code that has nothing to do with Gradle, dependencies or IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: It wasn't. I didnt change any code, and after the refresh, it started resolving. Also I spelt it right. `WebClient` was the issue - not `Builder`. However, you are right in saying the `builder()` method is lowercase, while the class is uppercase

Comment: Can you clarify equivalent pom.xml setting ? I don't use gradle

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue too, and I am using this dependency:

`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'`

I also had to invalidate IntelliJ caches at `File > Invalidate Caches`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33910478)