# why do I have to remove a dependency from my pom before adding it back and installing to get the latest version of my maven package?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, mvn-repo

I have a maven package I've hosted on GitHub package registry.

Whenever I make an update to the package I run  `mvn deploy` to publish the changes, but if I simply run `mvn install` on the dependent application it doesn't seem to install the latest version of the package. Only after deleting the `pom.xml` and then loading the changes into IntelliJ, then adding it back and running `mvn install` does it seem to get the new publication of the package.

This is my `settings.xml` file:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>github</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>github</id>
                    <name>GitHub COMPANY NAME Apache Maven Packages</name>
                    <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/***********</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>TaylorBurke</username>
            <password>****************</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Do I need to up the version of the package every time I publish a change? Maybe there's a configuration issue with Maven? Or perhaps this is the nature of the Maven plugin in IntelliJ?

Comment: Have you change the version between each install?

Comment: Use the SNAPSHOT dependency when developing so that you don't have the update the version every time.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm keeping the version the same in the pom.xml of the dependent application because I'm not updating the versioning in the package every time I make changes. Should I be?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I am currently on version 0.0.3-SNAPSHOT

Comment: perhaps I need to add   <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>  to the settings.xml file under the github repo?

Comment: There is a default update policy in Maven (usually set in [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#repositories)). Also this should be configured in IntelliJ. Or you can change the behaviour in your settings.xml file that will be picked up by IntelliJ as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select [this checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0aKM.png), if you want IntelliJ IDEA to update snapshots on [sync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192764/104891) and use the `SNAPSHOT` dependency if you don't update the version:

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Always update snapshots**.

Make sure to click the **Reimport** button in the Maven tool window to synchronize the changes.

Comment: I was hoping this would be it since the box wasn't previously checked, but it doesn't appear to have fixed the problem even after restarting IntelliJ...

Comment: Did you force reimport?