# How to fix POM Error destFile not allowed?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I'm trying to get my team to switch to IntelliJ from STS but I'm getting this error in the POM file that we don't see in STS.

The line below is throwing an error : "Element destFile is not allowed here"
This doesn't break anything but I just want to make sure there's no errors.

```
                    <destFile>${jacoco.exec.path}</destFile>
```

How can I resolve this error?

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*DTO.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Example.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/generated/**/*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/constants/**/*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/dto/**/*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/mapper/**/*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/model/**/*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/domain/**/*.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*.set*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*.get*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*.toString*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <destFile>${jacoco.exec.path}</destFile>
                    <dataFile>${jacoco.exec.path}</dataFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>target/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>target/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what version of the `jacoco-maven-plugin` you are using, but it looks like it doesn't support this configuration. Updating the plug-in to `0.8.5` version [seems to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoUT8.png).

Comment: Thank you! We were on 0.8.3

Comment: sorry it seems like i'm still getting it after doing mvn clean install

Comment: <jacoco.maven.plugin.version>0.8.5</jacoco.maven.plugin.version>

Comment: Do you get the error in IntelliJ IDEA or in the command line Maven build? Did you reimport the project per https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192764/104891? If the issue persists, please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since I can't reproduce it.