# Process 'command '/Users/alvinpeng/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.8.hs-adpt/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 255

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, intellij-idea, jdbc

When I tried to use java to connect my local server in Intellij, I got this error. I don't know what mistake it is, which part it comes from. Can anyone enlighten me? I already got the postgresql jdbc driver in libs.

When I run it with intellij, it said:

```
/Users/alvinpeng/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.8.hs-adpt/bin/java -javaagent:/Users/alvinpeng/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/202.7319.50/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=51001:/Users/alvinpeng/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/202.7319.50/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/alvinpeng/Desktop/program/out/production/classes:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/28.2-jre/8ec9ed76528425762174f0011ce8f74ad845b756/guava-28.2-jre.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/1dcf1de382a0bf95a3d8b0849546c88bac1292c9/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/b421526c5f297295adef1c886e5246c39d4ac629/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/25ea2e8b0c338a877313bd4672d3fe056ea78f0d/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.checkerframework/checker-qual/2.10.0/5786699a0cb71f9dc32e6cca1d665eef07a0882f/checker-qual-2.10.0.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.4/dac170e4594de319655ffb62f41cbd6dbb5e601e/error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/ba035118bc8bac37d7eff77700720999acd9986d/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar program.App
Unable to load the class. Terminating the program

Process finished with exit code 255
```

When I tried to run it with gradle, it said:

```
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 2592). The daemon log file: /Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/daemon/6.4/daemon-2592.out.log
Starting 7th build in daemon [uptime: 1 hrs 55 mins 42.971 secs, performance: 96%, non-heap usage: 22% of 268.4 MB]
Using 8 worker leases.
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/Users/alvinpeng/Desktop/program/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Users/alvinpeng/Desktop/program/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'program']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'program' using build file '/Users/alvinpeng/Desktop/program/build.gradle'.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'App.main()' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':compileJava', task ':processResources', task ':classes', task ':App.main()']
Tasks that were excluded: []
:compileJava (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
Caching disabled for task ':compileJava' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Skipping task ':compileJava' as it is up-to-date.
:compileJava (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.018 secs.
:processResources (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
Skipping task ':processResources' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
:processResources (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:classes (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':classes' as it has no actions.
:classes (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:App.main() (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :App.main() FAILED
Caching disabled for task ':App.main()' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':App.main()' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Starting process 'command '/Users/alvinpeng/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.8.hs-adpt/bin/java''. Working directory: /Users/alvinpeng/Desktop/program Command: /Users/alvinpeng/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.8.hs-adpt/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=AU -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/alvinpeng/Desktop/program/build/classes/java/main:/Users/alvinpeng/Desktop/program/build/resources/main:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/28.2-jre/8ec9ed76528425762174f0011ce8f74ad845b756/guava-28.2-jre.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/1dcf1de382a0bf95a3d8b0849546c88bac1292c9/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/b421526c5f297295adef1c886e5246c39d4ac629/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/25ea2e8b0c338a877313bd4672d3fe056ea78f0d/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.checkerframework/checker-qual/2.10.0/5786699a0cb71f9dc32e6cca1d665eef07a0882f/checker-qual-2.10.0.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.4/dac170e4594de319655ffb62f41cbd6dbb5e601e/error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar:/Users/alvinpeng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/ba035118bc8bac37d7eff77700720999acd9986d/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar program.App
Successfully started process 'command '/Users/alvinpeng/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.8.hs-adpt/bin/java''
Unable to load the class. Terminating the program
:App.main() (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.123 secs.
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':App.main()'.
> Process 'command '/Users/alvinpeng/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.8.hs-adpt/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 255
```

[image: here is my program's error]

get_connection function:

[image: get_connection function]

main function:

[image: main function]

Comment: [Disable build/run delegation](https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png), run it again as a Java Application instead of Gradle, what would be the error?

Comment: Did you try clicking that `Run with --info` thing? It should show a little bit more info about what's going on

Comment: same information when I tried to run with --info

Answer (score 0):

JDBC driver jar is not in the classpath.

> I already got the postgresql jdbc driver in libs

If you have it in the local directly for the Gradle based project you also need to adjust `build.gradle` file to include the local jars into classpath [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

However, it should be much easier to just include the repository dependency so that Gradle can download and configure the driver automatically.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.4-1206-jdbc42'
}
```

Not sure what JDBC driver version you need for this project. You can [check this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql) for all the available versions and adjust the dependency in `build.gradle`.

Don't forget to [reimport the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192764/104891) so that IDE knows about the new dependencies.

For the projects not using Gradle/Maven the JDBC jar needs to be added to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency) manually.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your help, but I still got the same error even if I add dependencies in build.gradle, it said: Process 'command '/Users/alvinpeng/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.8.hs-adpt/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 255

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your app is coded to exit with `-1` code on any error. Try printing the exception before every exit (or remove all the try/catch blocks and add the exceptions to the main method signature), then check the output for the exception stacktrace so that you can better understand the actual error.