# JFXPanel , MediaPlayer , Media classes doesn't work in netbeans 15.4 swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx

im trying to execute this code :

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       try {
          JFXPanel j = new JFXPanel ();
          String uri = new File ("Alex Clare - Too Close.mp3").toURI().toString();
          MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer (new Media (uri)).play(); 
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           
       }
```

my netbeans 15.4 didnt recognize those classes even i import them in the top of the program.what is the solution please ?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [JavaFX MediaPlayer import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976938/javafx-mediaplayer-import/69978264#69978264)

Comment: Your media player and player and media might get garbage collected if you don’t store references to them.

Comment: You aren’t using the JFXPanel. Perhaps [startup](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#startup(java.lang.Runnable)) the platform (once only) instead, if that is needed to play the mp3. If you do use the JFXPanel you need the javafx-swing dependency and to require the javafx.swing module, similar to javafx.media usage noted in the potential duplicate.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you can write your app using only JavaFX rather than mixing Swing, that is preferred.

Comment: [mcve] please - including the module info