# JavaFx Mediaplayer Import for jdk 19 doesnt work

Tags: javafx, import, dependencies, syntax-error, media-player

I have a issue, not being able to import MediaPlayer in my JavaFX project. I am using IntelliJ with a Maven build, JDK 19. I also looked here for answers but they didn't work for me: [JavaFX MediaPlayer import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976938/javafx-mediaplayer-import)

I have tried to fix by writing in **module-info.java** `requires javafx.media;` and
by adding `javafx-media` dependency, but it didn't work.

The only error is:
java: cannot find symbol

Thanks in advance for any answer/suggestion

> ```
> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>
>   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
>   <artifactId>MediaPlayer</artifactId>
>   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   <name>MediaPlayer</name>
>
>   <properties>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>     <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>      </properties>
>
>   <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>       <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
>       <version>19</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>       <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
>       <version>19</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
>       <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
>       <version>${junit.version}</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
>       <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
>       <version>${junit.version}</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>       <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
>       <version>19</version>
>     </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
>
>   <build>
>         <plugins>
>             <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>3.10.1</version>
>         <configuration>
>           <source>19</source>
>           <target>19</target>
>         </configuration>
>             </plugin>
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>0.0.8</version>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
> Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
>             <id>default-cli</id>
>             <configuration>
>               <mainClass>com.example.mediaplayer/com.example.mediaplayer.HelloApplication</mainClass>
>               <launcher>app</launcher>
>               <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
>               <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
>               <noManPages>true</noManPages>
>               <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
>               <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
>             </configuration>
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>       </plugin>
>           </plugins>
>   </build>
> </project>`
> ```

Comment: Does `requires javafx.media;` give an error? You may need to rebuild the maven project (which downloads dependencies and updates class/module paths, etc.), depending on your IDE.

Comment: The approach in the answer to the question you linked worked for me.  What does "doesn't work" mean?  You note a "syntax-error" in tags.  What is the syntax error?  A syntax error will create a compile error.  Provide the output of the compilation error in the question, the compile command used, and the code that doesn't compile so your issue can be replicated (e.g. [mcve]).  If it isn't actually a syntax error, but is a runtime error, then do the same, but provide the stack trace for the runtime error and the execution command to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple:
If the Intellij gives the error that it cannot find the symbol, just need to update Intellij from JetBrains ToolBox.