# java how do I get an image from a .mp4 video?

Tags: java, javafx, video-processing

I need to get an image as preview of the videos loaded by the users, it doesn't need to be a great thumbnail because it's just for a chat application, so I had in mind that when a user sends a message that contains an mp4 I process it and save a random frame as well.

I googled a bit and everyone is using ffmpeg but that's an external software and you can only interact with it with java, my project needs to be stand alone I don't want it to rely on the fact that the server has ffmpeg installed, so I went back in time and found JavaFX, but all the snippets online don't specify the version they're using and chatGPT is useless as always, can you guys show me how to do it or at least explain to me how it works so that I can code it myself? I'm using this dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>16</version> <!-- the version chatGPT wrote but you can change that -->
    </dependency>
```

if you have a different solution altogether that's great too I only care about saving a random frame from the video with the specified name at the specified path, thanks in advance

I tried this method but it gives plenty of errors probably because of a version mismatch

```
private byte[] getFrameFromVideo(String videoFilePath, int targetTimeSeconds) throws IOException {
        try {
            Media media = new Media(new File(videoFilePath).toURI().toString());
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

            mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.setStartTime(mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration().multiply(targetTimeSeconds * 1.0 / media.getDuration().toSeconds()));
                mediaPlayer.setStopTime(mediaPlayer.getStartTime().add(mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration().multiply(1.0 / media.getDuration().toSeconds())));
                latch.countDown(); 
            });

            mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(mediaPlayer.getMedia().getWidth(), mediaPlayer.getMedia().getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                FXImage fxImage = mediaPlayer.snapshot(null);
                fxImage.pixelReaderProperty().get().getPixels(0, 0, (int) fxImage.getWidth(), (int) fxImage.getHeight(), javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance(), bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer());

                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);
                    mediaPlayer.dispose();
                    latch.countDown(); 
                    return baos.toByteArray();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.play();

            latch.await();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: A "random frame"? How would you know that wasn't, say, a blank frame?

Comment: Think outside the box: don't use java for something standard tools already exist for, and just invoke `ffmpeg`, then read in the file that creates?

Comment: @Mike Loading external dependencies, especially those that come with unvetted native code is often a no-no for many deployment environments so this is a good question.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't, but unless _they_ say they can't, ffmpeg itself is always the better option.

Answer (score 5):

As you are using Maven, to use JavaFX Media, you need JavaFX media as a Maven dependency and also added to your Java module system.

- [JavaFX MediaPlayer import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976938/javafx-mediaplayer-import/69978264#69978264)

You need to start the JavaFX runtime to correctly use the Media system.

- See the [javadoc for application on the lifecycle and platform startup and shutdown options](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html).
- The JavaFX runtime should be started only once for the lifetime of your application.
- The JavaFX runtime should be shut down before your application exits.

JavaFX API calls to media should be made on the JavaFX application thread. The JavaFX application thread should never be slept or latched.

To play the media and ensure it is ready to take a snapshot at a chosen location:

1. Place the [`MediaView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaView.html) node in a [`scene`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html).
2. Implement [media error handling](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) if needed.
3. [`mute`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#muteProperty()) the media player.
4. Use Media APIs to skip to a
   location in the video using the [`seek`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#seek(javafx.util.Duration)) API.
5. Monitor the [`status`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#statusProperty)
   of the media player.
6. [`play`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#PlayingMediaInJavaFX) the video from the sought point.

After the status switches to playing, use [`Platform.runLater`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)), to give the system time to render the required frame.  And in the `runLater` call perform the next steps:

1. take a [`snapshot` of the `MediaView` node](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot(javafx.util.Callback,javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)).
2. then [`stop`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop()) the `MediaPlayer`.
3. and [`dispose`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#dispose()) of the player.

Your snapshot gives you a JavaFX [`image`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) you can directly display in a JavaFX [`ImageView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html).

If you need to save your snapshot image to disk:

1. After you take your snapshot, [convert the JavaFX `Image` to a `BufferedImage`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#fromFXImage(javafx.scene.image.Image,java.awt.image.BufferedImage))
   using the `javafx-swing` module.

   - added to your project similarly to `javafx-media`.
2. Write the buffered image to an appropriate format, e.g. `jpg` or `png` using [`ImageIO` apis](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,java.lang.String,java.io.File)).

   - if you choose to save as a jpg rather than a png, you might need to [remove the alpha channel](http://www.java2s.com/example/java/2d-graphics/remove-bufferedimage-alpha-channel.html), because jpg can’t handle alpha.

If your app is modular, then in your module-info include all of the required module dependencies to make this work:

- `javafx.media`
- `javafx.swing`
- `java.desktop`

**Recommended distribution**

To get your app functionality to end users, it is recommended to either:

- Use the [`maven-javafx-plugin`](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin), to create a [jlinked zip](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxjlink-options) of your app for your target platform,

  - Users can use your app by unzipping the zip and executing the app by invoking the shell script created by [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jlink.html).

OR

- Use the [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A) system to create an installer for your app or if your app is not modular.

  - Users can use your app by launching the installer to install the app on their system, which they can run as they do any other native app for the system.
  - Using `jpackage` to package a non-modular application and create installers for various platforms is more complex than creating jlink zip distributions for modular applications.

For either of the above methods, the user will generally not have to install any other software on the target machine in order to use your app.

**References**

- [Oracle JavaFX media tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm).

  - Somewhat dated, but still mostly relevant.
- [OpenJFX getting started](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

  - Make sure you can run the hello, world app from getting started before attempting the steps in this answer.

**Alternatives**

- As an alternative, [vlcj for JavaFX](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx) can also take video snapshots

  - but that requires [vlc](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to be installed and is more complex to use than JavaFX media.
- [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) could also be used to take snapshots, for which I believe there may be Java bindings (I don't know that for sure) or the native process could be called from the [Java process API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html)

  - but that also requires the native ffmpeg runtime to be available.
  - ffmpeg command-line instructions (I haven't tried this):

    - [How to extract one frame of a video every N seconds to an image?](https://superuser.com/questions/135117/how-to-extract-one-frame-of-a-video-every-n-seconds-to-an-image)