javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel import not working
I'm creating a project for school that requires me to use java swing and the api i chose has OAuth2 authentication so I decided that I could have one of my views have the browser embeded into it using JFX. For some reason though i've had trouble importing javafx.swing package into my project and the import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel; line does not recognize embed as a package available. I am using intellij IDEA with jdk 22 and I have javafx-swing version 23 loaded in as a dependency in my maven structure. Does anyone know if they changed the name of the package or if there's any other way to embed a browser into my java swing GUI. Any ideas would be appreciated.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>20.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>23</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>20.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>23</version> <!-- Add javafx-embed-swing -->
    </dependency>

I've tried changing versions in my maven dependency and i checked the documentation online to see if any name had changed to no avail.
EDIT-- The issue was that I was using different versions of JavaFX for all my JavaFX dependencies, changing them to ALL be version 20.0.1 seemed to work for me.

You say it's in your POM file, but double check that you have an appropriate version of this artifact declared as a dependency (note all JavaFX artifacts should be the same version). If you have a module-info.java file, make sure you have a requires javafx.swing; directive (or get rid of the module-info file). For more help, please [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Similar question (for javafx.media instead of javafx.swing): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69976938/javafx-mediaplayer-import

Hi @Slaw! Changing them to all be the same version in my maven dependencies was the fix I needed thank you so much. I'm sorry if my question was vague as well, this is the first time I ask anything on here. Thank you again I really appreciate it.

If you receive 15 reputation, you can self answer instead of placing the answer in an edit of the question.
