# "Cannot find method window()" in IntelliJ (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, cannot-find-symbol

So I'm learning Selenium for test automation with Java, and I have an error message like in the title, "window()" in IntelliJ is red .

I was trying to import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Options, but its grayed out, so useless.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Options;  //this one is grayed out

public class WindowsActivities {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine here: https://i.imgur.com/HQogLsN.png. What dependencies did you include in the project?

Comment: It will look better. https://i.imgur.com/Wv82fIW.png

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing this dependency (which also provides `selenium-api`):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Make sure you also have this dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

[Reload the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192764/104891) to update the dependencies.

[image: proof of work]

Please also try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Thank You CrazyCoder. Unfortunately, after adding this dependency, it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added all dependencies You've suggested, reloaded the project, Invalidated and restarted and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try removing the `test` scope from `pom.xml` if your code is not inside the test source roots.

Comment: OK. Thank You. Your last suggestion helped me to fix the problem. I copied the whole code into a different folder in the project. Instead of creating the class in src>test>java I created one in src>main>java. And now everything works. But hell, I have no idea why. Thank You so much.

Comment: The difference between main and test directories can lie in place where you add your dependencies, only for test directory or for main or for whole project

Comment: I thought that when I add a dependency, I add it to the whole project... So, how do I check if I added dependencies only to test, main or to the whole project? Cause it seems I totally don't understand now how my project structure works.

Comment: @Weronika Please see https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes.

Comment: Thank You so much, @CrazyCoder. That explained a lot.

Answer (score -1):

1. I recommend you to use `WebDriverManager`, that carries out the management of the drivers required by Selenium WebDriver: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager
2. Also I recommend you to use `Selenide`, build on Selenium, which has a lot more advantages, instead of pure Selenium: https://selenide.org/

It will make your work easier and faster