# IntelliJ IDEA cannot find the javafx.media module with Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am working with a colleague on a JavaFX application, using IntelliJ IDEA. His latest work included using the javafx.media module. I pulled his work and tried to launch it, but to no avail. I get the following error message :
`java: module not found: javafx.media`

I have checked the pom.xml file, to see if the dependency is actually present. Here are the first dependencies :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

The javafx-media module is present. Next, I checked the module-info.java file to see if it was called :

```
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.media;
```

However, only the javafx.media part is labelled in red. All the other modules are found and when I remove javafx.media and everything that descends from it, it runs.

Comment: Make sure to re-import the project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192764/104891.

Comment: Remove `<type>pom</type>` from the `javafx-media` dependency.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA even the Ultimate version doesn't support the media package, you have to install JMF(Java Media Framework) and set path in libraries. Here is the download link for JMF:"

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jmf-211e-download.html

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov Apps that use JavaFX media can be developed in Idea.  I do not recommend using JMF in a JavaFX app.  JMF is simply ancient. The hardware requirements are “166 MHz Pentium, 160 MHz PowerPC, or 166 MHz UltraSparc”.  Those are museum pieces.  I recommend using JavaFX media in JavaFX applications.  Or, in some corner cases like mkv file playback, the JavaFX library for vlcj.