# Intellij does not recognize import gradle/java/groovy

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Im new to java/intellij. Dont understand why the text still is in red when the package is added and it compiles[image]

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20190722'
}
```

Comment: Re-import the project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192764/104891.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this procedure.

1. attempt: Re-import Gradle Project. This can be done from menu located on the right side of IDE. It's like a card where you will see Gradle logo. (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/working-with-gradle/syncing-and-reloading/)
2. attempt: Clear IDE Cache. This can be done in File > Invalidate Caches (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html)
3. attempt: Use "Repair IDE" in File > Repair IDE. This will launch a wizard that will try to guide you with multiple functions. These will try to fix all problems that might caused by IntelliJ. (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/repair-ide.html)