# Error during artifact deployment [Tomcat 8.5.45]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

I cannot seem to resolve this import

`import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;`

I get the following error: Cannot resolve symbol 'mysql'

`java: package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist`

I tried finding a JAR on web thorugh Intellij IDA, however nothing solves it

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Maven or Gradle to manage your project dependencies.

If you are not using any of the external build systems, [download the jar manually](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and add it to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency) and to [the artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html).

You can also use the feature to [download the jar from Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#download-libraries-from-maven) in IntelliJ IDEA. For MySQL, you can use this Maven artifact: `mysql:mysql-connector-java`:

[image: mysql]

If using Maven, you need to adjust the `<dependencies>` section in your `pom.xml` to include MySQL dependency. Then you need to make sure this dependency [is also added in the artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) that you deploy to Tomcat.

Example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>
```

Don't forget to [refresh the dependencies/reimport the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192764/104891).

Comment: I'm using Maven, however when I click to Download Sources and Documentation, the error persistis

Comment: @RianRebouças See the updated answer for Maven-based projects.

Comment: Adding the dependency on the pom.xml file solved my problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC driver archive you probably need can be found in [MySql-Connector on Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j/8.3.0).

Download the jar and put it in the `lib` folder of your Tomcat.