# Setting up MongoDB with JavaFX in Intellij, MongoDB external Jar files throwing errors

Tags: java, mongodb, intellij-idea, javafx

**Background**

I am trying to run a MongoDB Database Accessor file in a JavaFX file on IntelliJ along with a basic main file, so far to connect with MongoDB I have added these external MongoDB jars to the Module dependencies (run<project structures<Modules<dependencies<add jars or directories). these

**Problem Description**
The following error repeats multiple times when I try to call/access the files from the jars with my DatabaseAccessor file. (I have also called the jar files in Module-info file as running the main file threw other errors if I didn't). At this point it says the whole project build fails.

This is the error
`java: the unnamed module reads package org.bson.types from both org.mongodb.bson and mongo.java.driver`

[image]

Comment: The project is Gradle based. All the dependencies must be added in `build.gradle` file, not manually in the IDE settings.

Comment: Interesting me and my teammates hadn't considered that as an option because we've never used Gradle before, we were expecting it to run normally i.e. by importing as jars into the java module

Comment: All the manual changes you make in the IDE dependencies settings are not used by the Gradle build and will be discarded on the next project re-import.

Comment: Also I don't think its Gradle, as it shows Maven directories in the folder

Comment: The same applies to Maven and all other external build systems supported by IntelliJ IDEA, [see the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78195468/error-during-artifact-deployment-tomcat-8-5-45/78195592#78195592) I answered recently.